# Pivot table in Python and MySQL

Tags: python, mysql

I am trying to lookup data from 2 tables in mysql using python.
This is what I have thus far, but it is giving the error "No result set to fetch from." I think because I have nested fetchall()'s

```
sqlu = "SELECT mob, contact, email, sms, quota FROM vonuser"
sqlq = "SELECT mobile, date, SUM(data) FROM mobtab GROUP BY date, mobile"
mycursori.execute(sqlq)
mycursoru.execute(sqlu)
for rowu in mycursoru.fetchall():
  print(rowu[0], rowu[1], rowu[2], rowu[3], rowu[4])
  for rowi in mycursori.fetchall():
    if int(rowi[2]) > var:
      print(rowi[0], rowi[1], rowi[2], '***overusage***')
    else:
      print(rowi[0], rowi[1], rowi[2])
```

I am not sure how to perform this type of lookup.
Thanks in advance,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out, hopefully this is useful to someone else.

I changed, this:-

```
sqlu = "SELECT mob, contact, email, sms, quota FROM vonuser"
sqlq = "SELECT mobile, date, SUM(data) FROM mobtab GROUP BY date, mobile"
mycursori.execute(sqlq)
mycursoru.execute(sqlu)
for rowu in mycursoru.fetchall():
  print(rowu[0], rowu[1], rowu[2], rowu[3], rowu[4])
  for rowi in mycursori.fetchall():
    if int(rowi[2]) > var:
      print(rowi[0], rowi[1], rowi[2], '***overusage***')
    else:
      print(rowi[0], rowi[1], rowi[2])
```

to this:

```
sqlu = "SELECT mob, contact, email, sms, quota FROM vonuser"
sqlq = "SELECT mobile, date, SUM(data) FROM mobtab GROUP BY date, mobile"
mycursoru.execute(sqlu)
for rowu in mycursoru.fetchall():
  print(rowu[0], rowu[1], rowu[2], rowu[3], rowu[4])
  mycursori.execute(sqlq) # moved this to here
  for rowi in mycursori.fetchall():
    if int(rowi[2]) > var:
      print(rowi[0], rowi[1], rowi[2], '***overusage***')
    else:
      print(rowi[0], rowi[1], rowi[2])
```